# Error while using NOT LIKE command in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

When I am using this syntax, it throws an error "demo column is not in field list",
but here demo is a string? Anything wrong with this query

```
mysql --batch --raw -h ${host} -u ${user} -p${pass} ${saas_db} -e'SELECT `CreationTime`  from `usagehistory` where IdentityName NOT like demo Order by CreationTime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, no. Backquotes or no quotes mean that you want to use it as an identifier. Single or double quotes are for strings.

Comment: here single quote are also not working but thanks double quotes works here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove back ticks on `demo` and use single or double Quote like

```
SELECT `CreationTime` from `usagehistory` where IdentityName NOT like 'demo' Order by CreationTime DESC LIMIT 1
                                                                       ^^^^
```

Back ticks only used for fieldName, TableName not for search field.